# NEO4J I try to do an foreach script with function but so fail

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I need to change some value in `Neo4J` list

I use `apoc.date.add` to change timestamp of my date but in foreach it's failed

This is my code:

```
MATCH path=(t:Trip)
FOREACH (n IN rels(path) | set SET n.EndTime = apoc.date.format(apoc.date.add(apoc.date.parse(n.EndTime,'ms',"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"),"ms",86400000,"ms"),"ms","yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")
```

But that does not work

can anyone help me

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed some typo errors in your Cypher query. Try it:

```
MATCH path=(t:Trip)
FOREACH (n IN rels(path) |
    SET n.EndTime = apoc.date.format(apoc.date.add(apoc.date.parse(n.EndTime,'ms',"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"),"ms",86400000,"ms"),"ms","yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")
)
```

Removed the extra `set` keyword and added an `)` in the end.

Comment: Hi @DladSbstin You are welcome! Also, if this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.